# Calling name for passing two arrays (a string and an int) to a function in C++

Tags: c++

I'm aware that when you write the call for your function you write it as displayArray(seasons,10)
with the name of one array and its size. I'm stuck on how you would right the arguments to pass the two arrays listed in my code, seasons and cartoons.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

void displayArray(string car[], int sea[], int size);


int main()
{
    int seasons[] = {5,10,8,2,12,7,31,9,3,4};
    string cartoon[] = { "Steven Universe","Adventure Time","Regular Show","Gravity Falls",
        "Spongebob Squarepants","Futurama","The Simpsons","Bob's Burgers","Avatar: The Last Airbender","Rick and Morty"};

    displayArray() // Error Message here
}

void displayArray(string car[], int sea[], int size)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        cout << "    " << car[x] << "\t\t" << sea[x] << right << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: `void displayArray(string car[]); displayArray(arrayOfFive);` Would something like that work? Or you might have to put it as a vector if you want a different number of parameters each time you call the function

Comment: I tried this, gives me "too many initializer values" message. We're not allowed to go into vectors in this intro class just yet so I don't think I could. I want to use the same size parameters. Do you know if a pointer or an ampersand would work in my case?

Comment: Oh, I actually answered your question. Hope I helped :)

Comment: You'd better avoid `type arr[], int size` function parameters. They are inherently unsafe, and in modern C++ we have better options.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to first create an array to pass your values with. Then just pass the array.

```
void function(int arr[]) {}

int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

function(arr);
```

So in your code above, it should look like this:

```
int main()
{
    int seasons[] = {5,10,8,2,12,7,31,9,3,4};
    string cartoon[] = { "Steven Universe","Adventure Time","Regular Show","Gravity Falls",
        "Spongebob Squarepants","Futurama","The Simpsons","Bob's Burgers","Avatar: The Last Airbender","Rick and Morty"};

    displayArray(cartoon, seasons, 10);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

displayArray(cartoon, seasons, 5);

This seems to work fine for me. You just pass each array in according to whichever is declared first in the function argument list. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: This was it! I was writing them in the wrong declaration order and then began to overthink and overcomplicate. I know it was such a simple solution but thanks you helped a lot!

Comment: No problem! I'm sorta new to c++ as well and this is definitely the kind of mistake I would make.